# Bigcommerce Category Header

Tags: variables, global, bigcommerce

Is there a variable for the category name? I'm trying to display the header of the category on the category page, but cannot find the global variable to use. The only variable i could think of was %%GLOBAL_CategoryName%%, but that didn't work.

Thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 1):

You are looking for %%GLOBAL_CatName%%

You can always check a free theme for some of these elements.

Comment: Thank you @developerscott . It worked. I looked at bigcommerce's list of global variables and they don't reference any that deal with cats. I tried upping the answer but i just joined and need a reputation of 15 in order to up your answer